# fold [IO Bool] with (&&) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For instance, we have:

```
flags :: [IO Bool]
```

What is the most concise way to fold `flags` with `(&&)`?

ie. To obtain the result if all flags (the elements of a list of `True` or `False` wrapped in `IO`) are `True` -> `True`, otherwise `False`

Please advise.

Comment: I suppose you want short-cut behaviour, i.e. it should only execute the actions until the first `False`? Otherwise it's simply `and <$> sequence flags`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks, could you give an example? I will accept that,

Comment: By the way, I prefer to obtain a value not execute-until manner.

Comment: Execute until? What do you mean? Do you want to perform all the actions even if one returns false?

Comment: @dfeuer See the answer.

Comment: Your edit didn't help anything. If I write `flags [pure False, False <$ putStrLn "Yoyo"]`, I know it needs to return `False`, but is it supposed to print "yoyo" or not?

Comment: @dfeuer Which edit are you talking about??

Comment: Please just answer my question in plain language. It's not hard.

Comment: Once you specify which edit you mention, I will.

Comment: There is a context of the Question and answer, and your code `flags [pure False, False <$ putStrLn "Yoyo"]`, is hard to find the context.

Comment: If you have a list of IO actions, they will not necessarily have been executed yet. Do you want to execute all IO actions in the list every time or do you only want to execute IO actions in the list until one gives back `False` and avoid executing the rest of the IO actions? This is the part that is unclear to me and others what you are looking for. For example, if `flags = [(putStr "a" *> pure True), pure False, (putStr "b" *> pure True)]`, do you want the printed output to be `a` or `ab`? Either behavior is possible, it just depends on what you want.

Comment: @DavidYoung Honestly, I did not consider such a performance issue, and actually, the reason this elements of the list is IO is as I clarify in my Q, it is flags, and mutable. `putStr` is way to extend in terms of the topic, and I do not care about the performing all sequence, because it should be trivial.

Comment: @DavidYoung To be fair, "This is the part that is unclear to me and others" or "it just depends on what you want." I think I made myself pretty clear on what I want. Flags. the reason of IO about mutation. `print` is out of scope of the code which can be easily read in the context of my Question. Why do you ask.

Comment: @Functor The reason I ask is that this is is not a performance issue. This is an issue about which behavior is correct. Imagine that one of the IO actions deletes a file or writes to a file, or sends a message over a network connection. Maybe you wouldn't want to run the "delete the file" action if you encountered a `False` earlier. Those would be two very different programs for reasons unrelated to performance. Also, if you read back through the comments I think that you will find everyone else who commented on the question was confused about what you wanted with regard to this issue.

Comment: @DavidYoung Ok, frankly, I really did not expect `flags :: [IO Bool]` will trigger the idea for `print` or `file` output. Again, my intention is not doing that, and if you ask me -depends on what I want. I do not want that. It's just to `read` mutated flag.

Comment: Making assumptions when answering questions often causes problems and miscommunication happens easily when you do. "flags" often has a certain meaning when it comes to computers, *but* maybe you're working on a forum system where people can flag posts. Maybe you're working in an area that uses specialized terminology that I'm not familiar with, where "flag" means something very different (this is not uncommon). I'd have to make an assumption about what you're asking and that assumption could be very wrong. It's much easier to tell us what you mean since, ultimately, only you know what you mean

Answer (score 3):

Using Hoogle to search for `Monad m => (a -> a -> a) -> [m a] -> m a` didn't produce any results, but when I [searched for](https://www.stackage.org/lts-18.25/hoogle?q=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%5Bm+Bool%5D+-%3E+m+Bool) `Monad m => [m Bool] -> m Bool` I found [`Control.Monad.Extra.andM`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.25/extra-1.7.9/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:andM):

```
-- | A version of 'and' lifted to a monad. Retains the short-circuiting behaviour.
andM :: Monad m => [m Bool] -> m Bool
```

which is exactly what's asked for.

Comment: Thanks, actually, this seems the answer and I try to try. The problem is I can't install `Contorol.Monad.Extra`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71167160/how-to-install-an-library-in-haskell

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to import `Control.Monad` and

```hs
foldr (liftM2 (&&)) (pure True) flags
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not `[Maybe Bool] ` but `[IO Bool]` as stated in Q.

Comment: So `pure True` instead of `Just True`, which modification will be accepted as answer.

Comment: Sorry, I will fix

Comment: Although I'm not 100% sure, but in Q comment thread, @dfeuer may mention my modification here to `pure` won't work.