# How to install an library in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I try to use
[Control.Monad.Extra.andM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.10/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html)

```
import Control.Monad.Extra (andM)
```

but has an error:

```
Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Extra’
Perhaps you meant
  Control.Monad.Catch (needs flag -package-key exceptions-0.10.4)
  Control.Monad.Error (needs flag -package-key mtl-2.2.2)
  Control.Monad.Except (needs flag -package-key mtl-2.2.2)not found
```

This error does not make sense.

According to

https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/installing-packages.html#installing-packages-from-hackage

> 3.2.1. Installing packages from Hackage
> The cabal tool also can download, configure, build and install a Hackage package and all of its dependencies in a single step. To do this, run:

```
$ cabal install [PACKAGE...]
```

> To browse the list of available packages, visit the Hackage web site.

Which says "in a single step", but in my experience this is too complicated and actually I have no idea how to install `Control.Monad.Extra` .

Usually, when a Haskeller want to install a specific library/package like this, how do you do this? There's no adequate documentations, it seems.

Answer (score 5):

> How to install an library in Haskell?

**You *don't*.** You should just *depend* on them, and then let Cabal worry about any installations that may need to be done. I.e., as you wrote

1. > Go to the Hackage page and study which exact library to be used.
2. > `*.cabal` file -> `build-depends: extra >=1.7.10`

   This is the crucial step. Your own Cabal file is the way to both specify what libraries are needed right now, as well as ensuring that everything will still work in the future. This file needs to specify both the packages you require, as well as the modules you're defining yourself.

   Probably you don't actually need `>=1.7.10`, but it can't hurt much to be specific there. [Standard practice](https://pvp.haskell.org/) is to add both lower and upper bounds on the `x.y` level, i.e. you'd use `extra >=1.7 && <1.8`, and then push the upper boundary as new versions come out. Arguably this is a bit overcautious; if you only use some simple tools from a package that is unlikely to have breaking changes in the future then it may be less trouble to just leave the upper boundary out.
3. > <del>`$ cabal install extra`</del>

   You've already specified that `extra` is needed for your project, no need to state that again. Instead, simply build your *own* project now.

   ```
   $ cabal build
   ```

   or, to get a GHCi prompt with your modules,

   ```
   $ cabal repl
   ```

   or, if you have an executable with a `main` that you wish to execute

   ```
   $ cabal run
   ```

   or if you want to install that executable (and *only* then)

   ```
   $ cabal install
   ```

   Cabal will then automatically figure out that `extra-1.7.10` should be installed first.

   (In old Cabal it would still have been necessary to run `cabal install --dependencies-only` first.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I have a question about that.

The reason I needed `$ cabal install extra --lib` is; in VS-Code, without it, the red `~~~~~~~` error won't go and the type-checker did not work on the `main.hs` for instance,  I understand `$ cabal build` works; however, to me, it's weird  to `buid/run`  before the completion of type-checking and confirmation of no compilation error.

Comment: I can't say how to set up VS code to properly interact with Cabal, but pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: Technically, with VS-code, `cabal install --dependencies-only` needs to be run.

Answer (score 2):

Ok Self-Answered. Comment me if the information is wrong.

**1. Go to the Hackage page and study which exact library to be used.**

[image]

In this case, it seems `extra-1.7.10`.

**2. `*.cabal` file ->  `build-depends: extra >=1.7.10` (among other libs)**

**3. `$ cabal install extra`**

Error:

> cabal: Cannot build the executables in the package extra because it does not contain any executables. Check the .cabal file for the package and make sure that it properly declares the components that you expect.

Well, I did for sure.

**4. `cabal install extra --lib`**

Finally works, but the documentation never said this.

Am I correct?
`
Is this the only method? or any other smarter way?